# Active Directory LDAP Search Filter or operator syntax

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am using LDAP Directory Services in C# to search users from LDAP with some filter criteria. I want to supply multiple OR filter criteria. For example firstName, lastName, telephone etc. It works fine when I supply all filter values but gives error when I just supply one or two filter values.

Here is the sample code I am using:

```
var LdapSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(RootDomain, 
                   "(&(objectclass=user)(sn=" + lastName.Trim() + ")(givenName=" + firstName.Trim() + "))");
```

I get the result when I supply both sn and givenName values. However, it's an OR search and user will enter either lastName or FirstName.

How to apply OR Filter in LDAP DirectorySearcher.?

Comment: `&` equals `AND` `|` equals `OR` do a google search.. there are actually lots of examples online on how to do this.. and if you want and even easier way.. google `PrincipalContext` examples as well with C#
[ActiveDirectory : LDAP Syntax](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the `|` operator. From what you've provided, your conditions are :

- `objectclass` must be equal "user"
- `sn` OR `givenName` must be equal to the provided value

Let's say the user has provided the name "John Smith". Your filter should look like :

`(&(objectClass=user)(|(sn=Smith)(givenName=John)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
var LdapSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(RootDomain, 
                   "(&(objectclass=user)" +
                    (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName.Trim())) ? "(sn=" + lastName.Trim() + ")" : "") +
                    (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName.Trim())) ? "(givenName=" + firstName.Trim() + ")" : "")
                    + ")");
```